# Exposing templates to user. Mako vs Jinja2 templating engines

Tags: python, jinja2, template-engine, mako

I'm trying to decide what template engine to use. We have decided to use Mako for the product but I don't know if it's a fit for my current project.

It seems like Jinja2 can run sandboxed to prevent the user from running python code like `users.delete`. Is there something similar in Mako?

In Jinja2 there is the loaders ([doc](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#loaders)). Is there something like it in Mako? I need it to be possible to load from database and not filesystem.

If there are other engine faster and with the above functionality included I'm all ears.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mako or Jinja2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435972/mako-or-jinja2)

Comment: well, not really... i'm looking for two specific things found in jinja2 but i can't figure out if they are also in mako.